# Magento2: Product page changes are reflecting immediately even if FPC is enabled

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

If you change related products or any other attribute from Magento2's backend, it reflects immediately on the storefront (even though FPC is enabled).

On closer inspection, it is found that it's calling the cache cleaning method on `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::beforeSave()`:

`$this->_cacheManager->clean('catalog_product_' . $this->getId());`

Is this a bug or feature in Magento2?

But I bet this is not what we expected. At least the changes done via backend should not be reflected unless the cache is refreshed.

What you say guys?

**== EDIT ==**

To disable the cache clear happening from backend, I simply removed the functionality from 
`Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope::clean()` as:

```
public function clean($mode = \Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL, array $tags = [])
{
    $result = true;
    /*if ($mode == \Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG) {
        $result = false;
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            if (parent::clean(\Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG, [$tag, $this->getTag()])) {
                $result = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($mode == \Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL) {
            $mode = \Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG;
            $tags = [$this->getTag()];
        } else {
            $tags[] = $this->getTag();
        }
        $result = parent::clean($mode, $tags);
    }*/
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Good point raised. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature!

Magento 2 out of the box will clear correct caches on the frontend depending on cache tags. Each entity that impacts the cache will have it's own tags. Once a product is saved all of the pages on which that product appears will be cleared. No need to flush the cache.

See more info here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-inval.html

> The Magento application enables you to clear cached content immediately after a entity changes. We use an IdentityInterface to link entities in the application with cached content and to know what cache to clear when an entity changes.

Comment: What will be the consequences if I remove the cache cleaning functionality from `beforeSave()` method?

Comment: Your cache will not be cleaned until you flush the page cache and block cache. If you really want to do this, you are better off creating a preference for the product model and rewriting \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::cleanCache so that it does nothing.